# fgetcsv to fetch data within double quotes

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I am trying to upload csv file data using PHP,

CSV File Data (Semicolon separated)

```
Name;Nom;Tel;Email;Ville;ID
x;DURAND;11;aprasquier+testvia@odm-tech.com;"Paris";1
```

PHP Code:

```
 $handle = fopen('test.csv', "r");
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle,0,  ";")) !== FALSE) 
      echo var_dump($data);
```

output:

```
array(1) { 
         [0]=> string(53) "x;DURAND;11;aprasquier+testvia@odm-tech.com;"Paris";1"
}
```

Expected output is ,

```
array(6) {
         [0]=> string(1) "x" 
         [1]=> string(6) "DURAND"
         [2]=> string(2) "11" 
         [3]=> string(31) "aprasquier+testvia@odm-tech.com"
         [4]=> string(5) "Paris" 
         [5]=> string(1) "1" 
}
```

Please anyone advise on this asap.

Comment: Mmmm, works for me, could you post all your code? i made a script to test your code and works well (PHP 5.3.10): `$handle = fopen("test.csv","r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle,0,  ";")) !== FALSE) print_r($data);`. What PHP version are you using?

Comment: updated post, we are just printing the csv row, entire row is coming in single array value. double quotes within "paris" makes problem.